# Is the image of the intersection of images of an automorphism equal to the intersection?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f : X \to X$ be a function. Define $A = \bigcap_{n \geq 0} f^n[X]$. Is $A = f[A]$?

I’m thinking this is right but also wondering if I’m missing something so obvious that I can’t see it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not true. It's true that $f[A] \subseteq A$. (If $a \in f^n[X]$ for every $n \geq 0$, then $f(a) \in f^{n+1}[X]$ for every $n \geq 0$, so in every $f^n[X]$ for every $n \geq 1$; and $f^0[X] = X$.) But the reverse containment doesn't have to hold.

Here's a counterexample, with $A \not\subseteq f[A]$. Let
$$
  X = \{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid 1 \leq m \leq n\} \cup \{(0,n) \mid n \leq 0 \}.
$$
Define $f : X \to X$ by
$$
  f(m,n) = \begin{cases}
    (m-1,n) & \text{if $m \geq 2$} \\
    (0,0)   & \text{if $m=1$} \\
    (0,n-1) & \text{if $m=0$}
  \end{cases}
$$
Now $(0,0) = f^n(n,n)$. But $(0,0) \neq f(x,y)$ for any $(x,y)$ such that $(x,y) \in f^n[X]$ for all $n \geq 0$. Indeed if $f(x,y) = (0,0)$ then $(x,y) = (1,n)$ for some $n \geq 1$, and $(x,y) = f^{n-1}(n,n)$, but $(x,y) \notin f^n[X]$.

If you'd prefer a representation as a directed graph ("dots and arrows") the idea here is that there is a point with an incoming path of length $n$, for every $n \geq 1$, and one single outgoing path.

Comment: Thanks—that helps a lot.

Comment: Can I ask whether there is a negative answer to this question if f is injective?

Comment: @ChristianHoffland If $f$ is injective, then $A = f[A]$. _Proof 1:_ Let $a \in A$ and for each $n$ let $x_n \in X$ s.t. f^n(x_n) = a$. Then $f(f^{n-1}(x_n))=a=f(x_1)$, so by injectivity, $f^{n-1}(x_n) = x_1$ for all $n$. Therefore $x_1 \in A$ and $a = f(x_1) \in f[A]$. The reverse inclusion is left to the reader. _Proof 2:_ Represent $f$ by a directed graph on $X$, with edges from $x$ to $f(x)$, so that each vertex has outdegree $1$. By injectivity each vertex has indegree $0$ or $1$. The connected components...

Comment: ... are finite cycles, "rays" (like $\mathbb{N}$), or "lines" (like $\mathbb{Z}$). Then $A = f[A] =$ the union of the cycles and "lines".